# Gulika and Mandi

Tags: puranas

I am interested in stories involing Gulika and Mandi, Shani's sons. Could somebody reference any mention of them in Puranas and other classical texts?

Comment: Sorry about that. The other question didn't show up in the search, as it was using different name and spelling, respectively.

Comment: Ok. No-problem.